# Order when calling ResolveAll in Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, dependency-resolver

Assume that I have multiple objects registered in the container, all implementing the same interface:

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<ITask>().ImplementedBy<Task1>(),
    Component.For<ITask>().ImplementedBy<Task2>(),
    Component.For<ITask>().ImplementedBy<Task3>(),
    Component.For<ITask>().ImplementedBy<Task4>(),
);
```

And I wish to resolve all the implementations of ITask:

```
var tasks = container.ResolveAll<ITask>();
```

Is there a way to control the order of the resolved instances?

Note: Obviously, I can implement an `Order` or `Priority` property on ITask, and just sort the list of tasks, but I am looking for a lower-level solution.

Comment: +1. This problem really bugs me since the handler filter needs to know something about implementations to sort them. I hope you will get some better ways to do it out of your question :)

Comment: @samy I'm totally with you, mate. But, I have to admit that this is not Windsor castle's problem. To the best of my knowledge -sorting entities/component is part of a system's business logic and which is obviously not what Windsor Castle was created for. It might have gone a bit far with a few "cool" features

Comment: @Saguiltay if you are concerned about adding too many dependencies to windsor castle's initialization -ironic DI and IoC are supposed to break dependencies- then you should create a wrapper component that does all the logic of sorting, filtering, etc. Make it implement an interface that exposes a method to return these tasks and finally, register this wrapper as you'd normally would with Windsor Castle

Comment: @Leo I totally agree. In fact I read mookid8000 blog post about its sorting system which was exactly how I envisionned doing it; don't use absolute order but try and coax some adequate order from requirements (a before b, c after a, etc). My frustration certainly comes from the fact that the doc was not very explicit on these features

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that what you are looking for is a **Handler Filter** which based on the scarce documentation and the breaking changes in Windsor Castle 3; it provides filtering and sorting of components. Here's an extract from their Wiki page

> The interface is similar to IHandlerSelector but allow you to
>   filter/sort handlers requested by container.ResolveAll() method

So basically you will need to implement the `IHandlerFilter` interface and then add this implementation to the kernel while initializing the Windsor container. From the [source code](https://github.com/mookid8000/Castle.Windsor/blob/master/src/Castle.Windsor/MicroKernel/IHandlerFilter.cs), this interface looks something similar to this...

```
public interface IHandlerFilter
{
    bool HasOpinionAbout(Type service);
    IHandler[] SelectHandlers(Type service, IHandler[] handlers);
}
```

Adding the **Handler Filter** to the kernel would be something like below...

```
 var container = new WindsorContainer()
        .Install(Configuration.FromXmlFile("components.config"));
        container.Kernel.AddHandlersFilter(new YourHandlerFilterImplementation());
```

and then when resolving all components of a services with `ResolveAll` the order will be sorted (and filtered) based on your own implementation

Answer (score 4):

I second Leo's advice that what you're after is a *handlers filter*.

On my blog I have [this example on how a simple handlers filter can be made](https://mookid.dk/2011/08/10/castle-windsor-resolution-logic-handler-filters/), which happens to be one that results in ordered task instances when they're resolved through `ResolveAll<ITask>` (or when an `IEnumerable<ITask>` gets injected):

```
class TaskHandlersFilter : IHandlersFilter
{
    readonly Dictionary<Type, int> sortOrder = 
        new Dictionary<Type, int>
        {
            {typeof (PrepareSomething), 1},
            {typeof (CarryItOut), 2},
            {typeof (FinishTheJob), 3},
        };

    public bool HasOpinionAbout(Type service)
    {
        return service == typeof(ITask);
    }

    public IHandler[] SelectHandlers(Type service, IHandler[] handlers)
    {
        // come up with some way of ordering implementations here
        // (cool solution coming up in the next post... ;))
        return handlers
            .OrderBy(h => sortOrder[h.ComponentModel.Implementation])
            .ToArray();
    }
}
```

I also have a [more elaborate example](https://mookid.dk/2011/08/15/castle-windsor-resolution-logic-cool-handler-filter-that-orders-components/) that plays around with the API used to specify the ordering - in this case, I'm allowing for the types to specify their position relative to another type, e.g. like

```
[ExecutesBefore(typeof(ExecutePayment))]
public class ValidateCreditCards : ITask { ... }
```

which might/might not be useful in your concrete situation :)